# python 2.7 IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:

Tags: python-2.7

At work I had the bad luck to have fix a badly written url validator script in python done by someone else. It's a really messy code, and trying to fix one of the bugs, I found some behavior that I don't understand.

The script has to process a file with around 10 thousand url's in it, it has to check each url to see if it's valid, not only in it's structure but also check if it exists (using pycurl for this). On one part of the code, this is done:

```
for li in lineas:
    liNew = "http://" + li
    parsedUrl = urlparse.urlparse(liNew)
```

On this case the bug was the addition of "http://" at the beginning of the line as that was  being done before on the script. So I changed the code to this:

```
for li in lineas:
    liNew = li
    parsedUrl = urlparse.urlparse(liNew)
```

Now, with the same input file the script fails with the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:/path/to/file/being/written/to.txt
```

With *liNew = "http://" + li*, file descriptors don't go over the default limit of 1024, but changing that line to *liNew = li* will make them go over 8000, why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With liNew = "http://" + li, file descriptors don't go over the default limit of 1024, but changing that line to liNew = li will make them go over 8000, why ??

- before: broken url - nothing gets downloaded (no files are opened)
- after: correct url - urls are saved to files (there are 10K urls)

It probably doesn't make sense to download more that a few hundreds urls concurrently (bandwidth, disk). Make sure that all files (sockets, disk files) are properly disposed after the download (`close()` method is called in time).

Default limit (1024) is low but don't increase it unless you understand what the code does.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'm rewriting the whole thing, it's such a mess that I was easier to start from scratch.