# Nibabel: IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:

Tags: python, macos, io

I have a python program, which generates multiple threads that extracts patches corresponding to various organs from set of common image files. It was all fine until I created an extra thread after which I started encountering IO Error 24: Too many open files.

It appears that nibabel framework, which I use to load medical images, leaves the file open. I am unsure if there is anyway I could force the API to close the file after reading.

I request someone to please help me with this, it is fine if I have to use a different framework, but please make sure that it provides an option to close the file after loading it though.

Comment: Did  you remember to close the files with file.close()?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by file. If you are on about what object nibabel is returning, then that is not possible since it just returns raw data of that image i.e., matrix. There is no function provided with the API that allows the file to be closed.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure then, but there are duplicate questions. Take a look at them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280612/ioerror-errno-24-too-many-open-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051968/python-2-7-ioerror-errno-24-too-many-open-files

Comment: @Janekmuric: I have seen that link, my question is specific to python medical image library nibabel, which is not closing the files after reading.

Comment: I am having the same issue - did you ever manage to resolve it?

Comment: If you use `nib.load`, it has a `kepp_file_open` flag, that you could set to `False` I don't know if that helps you. I get the same error even with the flag.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094535/oserror-errno-24-too-many-open-files-using-nibabel/69085145#69085145). Not sure if it solves your multiple thread problem, but it solves the problem of too many open files when reading in a bunch of NIfTI images