# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files using Nibabel

Tags: python, image, macos, operating-system, medical

I have a python3.6 program, using nibabel package to analyze medical images in NIFTI format.

```
import glob
import nibabel as nib
health = [nib.load(pt) for pt in glob.glob(healthdir+'*.nii')] # len = 200
health_data = [h.get_data() for h in health]
```

It occurred `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` in the last line. I used following code and found out that it occurred the error in the last element.

```
health_data = []
for i in range(len(health)):
    try:
        health_data.append(health[i].get_data())
    except:
        print(i) # 199
```

I have tried to search relative topic such as 
[Nibabel: IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798974/nibabel-ioerror-errno-24-too-many-open-files). However, it doesn't solve the problem. Also, I prefer not to use `ulimit`. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @djfire , did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not familliar with Nibabel but Try `with`

```
    health_data = []
    for filepath in glob.glob(healthdir+'*.nii'):
       with nib.load(filepath) as health:
           health_data.append(health.get_data())
```

**NOT TESTED

Comment: `AttributeError: __enter__`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete the object after using it.

```
def show_origin_image(name,s=100,max_limit=None, min_limit=None):
    origin = name
    file_name_list = [each for each in os.listdir(origin) if not each.startswith('.')]
    file_name_list = file_name_list[min_limit:max_limit]
    dimension = 2
    width_num = 6
    height_num = math.ceil(len(file_name_list) / width_num)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, height_num * 2.8))
    data_list = []
    for n,each in enumerate(file_name_list, 1):
        agent = nib.load(os.path.join(origin, each), keep_file_open=False)
        three_d_data = np.asarray(agent.dataobj)
        size = three_d_data.shape
        image = np.take(three_d_data, s, dimension)
        plt.subplot(height_num, width_num, n)
        plt.imshow(image, 'gray')
        plt.axis('off')
        data_list.append(three_d_data)
        # add delete operation!
        del agent
    return data_list
```

Comment: Got the same problem and deleting the object does not help. However my loop stopped at image 4005 (from 10 000). So neither the last nor the 200th element. But that might come from the powerful server I am working on

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem importing a number of self generated NIfTI images.
Using `nilearn` instead of `nibabel` solved the problem for me.

```
from nilearn.image import smooth_img
import glob
image_dir = glob.glob(some_path + '*.nii')
images = smooth_img(image_dir, fwhm=None)
image_maps = []
for img in images:
    img_data = img.get_fdata()
    image_maps.append(img_data)
    del img_data
```

Worked with 10 000 images for me and took around 12min. 
`smooth_img` reads in the nifti and applies a smoothing kernel with size `fwhm` (full width half maximum... I think). I did this because it works and I need this smoothing in a different situation in the script. You can check out `nilear.image.load_img`. It should do the same.

Best